# Compressing Javascript code having classes

Tags: javascript, class, compression, phpstorm

I am writing in Javascript using classes. Example:

```
'use strict';

class MyClassName
{
    myGame;

    constructor(game)
    {
        this.myGame = game;
    }

    startGame()
    {
        this.startActions();
    }

    startActions()
    {
      // 
    }
}
```

When i try to compress it in PhpStorm by using Assets Compressor, i get error:
**[ERROR] 3:6:identifier is a reserved word**

How i can make correct compressing my code in PhpStorm? Are there any ways to compress JS code that uses classes?

Comment: To "compress" it would probably require you to convert this to CJS.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/minifying-javascript.html#ws_minifying_js_run_compressor) helps you

Comment: Class is added in ECMAS2015, maybe your compressor works in earler standart

Comment: Are you talking about [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6740-assets-compressor/reviews)? If you check the reviews, it hasn't been updated since 2012 apparently

Answer (score 0):

[Assets Compressor](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6740-assets-compressor) plugin only supports ECMAScript 2015, it will throw errors on new syntax.

Please try following the instructions from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/minifying-javascript.html: install either [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) or the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) and set it up as a [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-file-watchers.html) to run from the IDE